# How to generate continuous time series data based on pattern matching output in large file list in R?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, merge, pattern-matching

I have projected data attribute table in .`csv` format where all German weather station was projected to respective Germany district level polygon shapefile by using `QGIS`, and this file can be found at [Projected Data](http://jmp.sh/LeNV1cI). I also cleaned historical weather data of Germany (from ftp server: [Germany weather data](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/monthly/kl/historical/)), and data are available on the fly: [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC).

However, in [Projected Data](http://jmp.sh/LeNV1cI) attribute table, each weather station has identical `Stationsname`  and `NAME_2` attribute but it has different `station.Identification` because it contains a different period of historical weather data, where its respective weather data were stored in [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC). I need continuous 35 years data to analyze but each station's different period' historical data were stored in a respective .csv file with a unique `Station.Identification` number (5 digit number).

here is how the projected data look like (`.csv` data can be available at fly:[Projected Data](http://jmp.sh/LeNV1cI) ):

```
> joinedData[1:10,]
   Stationsname Stations_ID ID__Index Station.Identification   Width Length Station_Height River_Basin Federal_state
1          Aach           1        KL                  00597 47.8410 8.8490            478          NA            BW
2          Aach           1        RR                  08334 47.8410 8.8490            478          NA            BW
3    Aach/Hegau       10771        PE                  02171 47.8500 8.8500            480          NA            BW
4        Aachen           3        EB                  00286 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
5        Aachen           3        FF                  00286 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
6        Aachen           3        KL                  00286 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
7        Aachen           3        MI                  00286 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
8        Aachen           3        MN                  01901 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
9        Aachen           3        PE                  05647 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
10       Aachen           3        RR                  10600 50.7827 6.0941            202      803100            NW
        Begin        End ID_0 ISO  NAME_0 ID_1               NAME_1 ID_2                 NAME_2   HASC_2 CCN_2 CCA_2
1  01.01.1937 30.06.1986   86 DEU Germany    1 Baden-WÃƒÂ¼rttemberg   22               Konstanz DE.BW.KN     0  8335
2  01.01.1912 30.06.1986   86 DEU Germany    1 Baden-WÃƒÂ¼rttemberg   22               Konstanz DE.BW.KN     0  8335
3                          86 DEU Germany    1 Baden-WÃƒÂ¼rttemberg   22               Konstanz DE.BW.KN     0  8335
4  01.01.1951 31.03.2011   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
5  01.01.1937 31.03.2011   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
6  01.01.1891 31.03.2011   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
7  28.04.1993 07.10.2008   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
8  01.10.2008 03.04.2012   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
9                          86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
10 01.01.1891 31.03.2011   86 DEU Germany   10  Nordrhein-Westfalen  290 StÃƒÂ¤dteregion Aachen DE.NW.AC     0  5334
      TYPE_2 ENGTYPE_2 NL_NAME_2 VARNAME_2
1  Landkreis  District        NA          
2  Landkreis  District        NA          
3  Landkreis  District        NA          
4      Kreis  District        NA          
5      Kreis  District        NA          
6      Kreis  District        NA          
7      Kreis  District        NA          
8      Kreis  District        NA          
9      Kreis  District        NA          
10     Kreis  District        NA
```

Here is how list of historical weather data of Germany looks like (all 1080 `txt` file can be found at [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC)):

```
> files[1:10]
 [1] "produkt_klima_monat_17190101_20161231_00403.txt"
 [2] "produkt_klima_monat_17570301_19611130_01425.txt"
 [3] "produkt_klima_monat_17810101_20161231_02290.txt"
 [4] "produkt_klima_monat_17880101_20161231_05099.txt"
 [5] "produkt_klima_monat_17920101_19840731_04927.txt"
 [6] "produkt_klima_monat_18010101_19531231_03382.txt"
 [7] "produkt_klima_monat_18240101_20161231_02444.txt"
 [8] "produkt_klima_monat_18300101_19621231_00402.txt"
 [9] "produkt_klima_monat_18340101_20161231_03126.txt"
[10] "produkt_klima_monat_18350101_20020331_01891.txt"
```

To do this, I come up with this possible pipeline:

1. in [Projected Data](http://jmp.sh/LeNV1cI), each station has identical `StationsName` and `NAME_2` attribute but it has different `Station.Identification` attribute, so I intend to extract each individual station based on a combination of identical `Stationsname` and `NAME_2`), where look up `Station.Identification` attribute will be important for next operation).
2. then based on extracted each station or row (each row must have identical `NAME_2` but may have slightly different `Stationsname`) with `Station.Identification` column, so uses it as a query to find 5 digits `Station.Identification` number from file lists in [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC), where each file in [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC) was named with 5 digit number at the end.
3. based on this match result, I intend to merge these `.txt` file in [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC) to generate continuous time series data for each station where the result can be named as `Stationname`+`NAME_2`.csv`.

I believe this requires a bit of regular expression handling and pattern matching experiences in R, I have a hard time to accomplish this in R easily because few experiences in `REGEX`. I need continuous data record for each individual station, I have to merge `txt` files in [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC) based on its matched `Station.Identification` which both appeared in [Projected Data](http://jmp.sh/LeNV1cI) and name extension of `txt` files in [German historical data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/4nMtQFC). How can I make this happen in R easily? Is there any workaround to get those done in R more efficiently? Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You have little experience with _REGEX_. I have no experience in _R_. Therefore, to get a regex you have to either get someone with a lot of experience in R _and_ regex. Otherwise, you have to pare down the R verbatim and turn it into casual terms and a lot of examples. Regex is a separate language really, and not really an other language dependency ( contrary to what some say ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dan this data is a bit complex to create examples  but here are some pseudo code ideas to help. THe names below are more general and don't exactly tie to your dataset.  The `tidyverse` library which includes `tidyr` and `dplyr`, is a great tool for these problems.

Beigin by always combining multiple csv into a single dataframe, adding the `file_name` as a column.  Function `separate` makes multiple columns from a single column.  So something like below creates new columns `station_id` and `obs_date` from a `file_name` column by separating  on _

```
new_df <- df %>%
  separate(file_name, c("station_id", "obs_date"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE)
```

For the regex or string manipulation look at `stringr` library. The `mutate` function create new columns. So something like

```
new_df <- df %>%
  mutate(observation_date = as.Date(obs_date), new_id = str_extract("\\5d"))
```

Here is a pipeline concept for matching

```
library(tidyverse)

## pseudocode

## for the first set of files build a reference
ref1 <- first_set %>% 
  select(name1, name2, station_id) %>%
  distinct() %>%           # unique combinations
  mutate(new_id = ....)    # add regex or formattinf

## for the second set of files build a reference
ref2 <- second_set %>%
  select(name1, name2, other_station_id) %>%
  distinct() %>%              # unique combinations
  mutate(new__id =  .... )    # add regex or formatting or whatever

## now join the reference to get a cross reference table
## missing entries wil have NA. 
ref <- full_join(ref1, ref2, by = "new_id")

## when your refernce table is looking clean then you can append the new ids
ref1 <- ref1 %>%
  left_join(ref, by = c("name1", "name2", "station_id")) %>%
  select(- ) ## use - to drop values not needed

ref2 <- ref2 %>%
  left_join(ref, by=c("name1", "name2", "other_station_id" )) %>%
  select(- )  ## use - to drop values not neede
```

now both these have a new_id column which can be used in join or other matching